# How to use outer field name or alias in a nested subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would use the selected field Referencia in the subquery.

I have tried including the field name the alias, and table name but not works.

How I can achieve this ?

Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
      articulos.Codigo AS Referencia,    
      articulos.Nombre AS Descripcion,
      barras.Codigo AS [Codigo de Barras],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY articulos.Codigo ORDER BY 
      articulos.Codigo ASC) as cantidad,
      articulos.Familia,
      articulos.Marca,              
      categorias.Codigo as Categoria,
      articulos.ImpuestoEspecial AS Ecotasa,
      articulos.Fase,
      articulos.Iva,
     --
     -- Tarifa1
     (  SELECT [Codigo],[EuroPrecio]
        FROM [GES16100].[dbo].[Tarifas] 
        WHERE [Codigo] = 1 AND [Articulo] = <------- Here, Referencia
     )AS T1,    
     articulos.Proveedor,
     articulos.GUID_Registro
     FROM [GES16100].[dbo].[Articulos] as articulos
        FULL JOIN [GES16100].[dbo].[Barras] as barras
            ON articulos.Codigo = barras.Articulo
        FULL JOIN [GES16100].[dbo].[Categorias_Asignaciones] catasignaciones
            ON catasignaciones.GUID_RegistroFichero =articulos.GUID_Registro                    
        FULL JOIN [GES16100].[dbo].[CategoriasFicheros] categorias
            ON categorias.GUID_Registro = catasignaciones.GUID_Categoria                                

)AS supersub
WHERE supersub.cantidad = 1
```

Comment: use articulos.Codigo

Comment: @etsa I have tried it and not works. Need Exists, but I can't understand how use EXiSTS in this scope

Comment: have you tried    WHERE [Codigo] = 1 AND [Articulo] = articulos.Codigo    ? What is error you obtain?

Comment: pls see what Gordon told you (you can't use two field in your subselect) and pls rewrite your question more clearly posting sample data and expected results if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table aliases and qualified column names whenever you have more than one table in a query.

Second, your subquery will not work because it returns two columns where one is expected.

For your example, I am guessing:

```
( SELECT t.EuroPrecio
   FROM [GES16100].[dbo].[Tarifas]  t
   WHERE t.Codigo = 1 AND t.Articulo = a.Codigo
) AS T1,
```

You cannot use the column alias `Referencias` because it is defined in the same `SELECT`.  Just use the column it is refering to.